# Use Ionic Tabs for Actions

Tags: android, ionic2, ionic3

I really like the style of the Tabs in Ionic 3 when you have an icon and a text:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#tabs-icon-text

However in the App I am using I have 4 Actions. For example open the Camera, open Google Maps and so on. And this I want to display on the bottom of the page exactly in this kind of style.

How can I achieve this, since this is not the real purpose of the Tabs and since I haven't found a similar Component.

Answer (score 1):

Just like you can see in [the Tab docs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tab/#usage):

> Sometimes you may want to call a method instead of navigating to a new
>   page. You can use the `(ionSelect)` event to call a method on your class
>   when the tab is selected.

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab (ionSelect)="chat()" tabTitle="Show Modal"></ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
```

And then

```
export class Tabs {
  constructor(public modalCtrl: ModalController) {}

  chat() {
    let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(ChatPage);
    modal.present();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. However how do I handle now the page which is shown, since all of my Tabs are calling a method. And currently the first one is highlighted.

Comment: I've done the following in an app I've worked on in the past: you could still set a page as root in each of these tabs, and the content could be just an image or some help text. That way when clicking on each tab icon, you'll still see something related to that tab on the background, the icon would be marked as selected, and the action (open the Camera, open Google Maps...) will be executed. Does it make sense in the context of your app?

Comment: Ok I will now try to set the same root page for every element and try to intercept the styling, when something is selected, so it always looks the same. :)

Comment: Sounds great! Please let me know how it goes :)